# Add data to JSON object as item

Tags: php, arrays, json, api

I want to add new item to my JSON that is data from my database.

This is my JSON now:

```json
{
    "0": {
        "idNegocio": "44",
        "nombre": "Brotherhood Barber Shop",
        "categoria": "19",
        "sector": "Guarocuya",
        "lat": "18.459985",
        "log": "-69.956607",
        "portada": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/cenda-negocios.appspot.com/o/negocios-portada-manuelarturosanz@gmail.com_1651997898285?alt=media",
        "icono": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/cenda-negocios.appspot.com/o/negocios-logo-manuelarturosanz@gmail.com_1651997897203?alt=media",
        "estado": "0",
        "rnc": "",
        "numeroContacto": "null",
        "patrocinado": "0",
        "disabled": "0",
        "unique_id": "UK4HQ03993",
        "ofertas_disponiles": "0",
        "created_at": "2022-05-08 04:18:18",
        "id": "19",
        "nombreCategorias": "Barberías",
        "icon": "categorias/iconos/razooor.png",
        "color": "#FFD929",
        "negocioID": null,
        "promedio": null
    },
    "1": {
        "idNegocio": "45",
        "nombre": "Barbarians Barbershop",
        "categoria": "19",
        "sector": "Piantini",
        "lat": "18.479420",
        "log": "-69.940588",
        "portada": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/cenda-negocios.appspot.com/o/negocios-portada-manuelarturosanz@gmail.com_1652000719781?alt=media",
        "icono": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/cenda-negocios.appspot.com/o/negocios-logo-manuelarturosanz@gmail.com_1652000718400?alt=media",
        "estado": "0",
        "rnc": "",
        "numeroContacto": "null",
        "patrocinado": "0",
        "disabled": "0",
        "unique_id": "FP0IIITXVJ",
        "ofertas_disponiles": "0",
        "created_at": "2022-05-08 05:05:25",
        "id": "19",
        "nombreCategorias": "Barberías",
        "icon": "categorias/iconos/razooor.png",
        "color": "#FFD929",
        "negocioID": null,
        "promedio": null
    },
    "imagen": "1278.jpg"
}
```

I would like to add "imagen" for each item of the array, as you see here it's outside. I want to put everything together.

Like this:

```json
{
    "0": {
        "idNegocio": "44",
        "nombre": "Brotherhood Barber Shop",
        "categoria": "19",
        "sector": "Guarocuya",
        "lat": "18.459985",
        "log": "-69.956607",
        "portada": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/cenda-negocios.appspot.com/o/negocios-portada-manuelarturosanz@gmail.com_1651997898285?alt=media",
        "icono": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/cenda-negocios.appspot.com/o/negocios-logo-manuelarturosanz@gmail.com_1651997897203?alt=media",
        "estado": "0",
        "rnc": "",
        "numeroContacto": "null",
        "patrocinado": "0",
        "disabled": "0",
        "unique_id": "UK4HQ03993",
        "ofertas_disponiles": "0",
        "created_at": "2022-05-08 04:18:18",
        "id": "19",
        "nombreCategorias": "Barberías",
        "icon": "categorias/iconos/razooor.png",
        "color": "#FFD929",
        "negocioID": null,
        "promedio": null,
        "imagen": "1278.jpg"

    },
    "1": {
        "idNegocio": "45",
        "nombre": "Barbarians Barbershop",
        "categoria": "19",
        "sector": "Piantini",
        "lat": "18.479420",
        "log": "-69.940588",
        "portada": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/cenda-negocios.appspot.com/o/negocios-portada-manuelarturosanz@gmail.com_1652000719781?alt=media",
        "icono": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/cenda-negocios.appspot.com/o/negocios-logo-manuelarturosanz@gmail.com_1652000718400?alt=media",
        "estado": "0",
        "rnc": "",
        "numeroContacto": "null",
        "patrocinado": "0",
        "disabled": "0",
        "unique_id": "FP0IIITXVJ",
        "ofertas_disponiles": "0",
        "created_at": "2022-05-08 05:05:25",
        "id": "19",
        "nombreCategorias": "Barberías",
        "icon": "categorias/iconos/razooor.png",
        "color": "#FFD929",
        "negocioID": null,
        "promedio": null,
        "imagen": "1278.jpg"

    }
}
```

This is my PHP code:

```php
<?php 
require '../../database/headers.php';
require '../../database/credentials.php';

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM negocios a INNER JOIN categorias ON a.categoria = categorias.id LEFT JOIN (SELECT negocio as negocioID, round(avg(valoracion),1) as promedio from reviews GROUP BY negocioID) b on a.idNegocio = negocioID WHERE a.disabled = 0 ORDER BY RAND()");
$rows=array();
while ($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
   
    $rows[]=$r;
   
   
}

foreach ($rows as $value) {
    $destinations[] = $value['lat'].','.$value['log'].'|';
 }
 $stringDestinations = implode("", $destinations);
 $distance_data = file_get_contents('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?destinations='. $stringDestinations .'&origins=Azua&units=km&key=AIzaSyCbeeustl3bZAC-FvEEr7WgEqY_pCi-A7M&language=es-ES&');
 $distance_arr = json_decode($distance_data);
 $durations = array();
 if (isset($distance_arr->rows[0])) {

   $probando = $distance_arr->rows[0]->elements;

   $pruebafinal = json_encode($probando);
}
$rows['imagen'] = "1278.jpg";
echo json_encode($rows);

?>
```

Comment: How is this a duplicate question? Adding data to json file is different than adding data to an json object elements.

Comment: Can you help me to see how can I do this?

Comment: `Adding data to json file is different than adding data to an json object`...no it isn't. Because the process of updating a JSON file is: 1) read JSON data from file, 2) decode into object in PHP, 3) update object, 4) encode to JSON, 5) write JSON to file. So you only really need to skip steps 1 and 5.

Comment: `$rows['imagen'] = "1278.jpg";` makes no sense compared to your requirements - that would add a single item to the top-level of the array, but you said you wanted to write it to each individual item. So you need to write something back to it within your loop. Here's the general idea: https://3v4l.org/TOsmq